# How to access a member of a list inside a delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

Well I think the title of this question is far to be clear but I hope the text below can clarity it.

The code below is a concept only but illustrates what I'm trying to do. How can I access a member of a List (inside the delegate) returned by a method without assigning it to a local List variable? Is that possible?

```
    static void ListTest()
    {
        int count = 0;

        List<int> even = Load().FindAll(delegate(int x)
        {
            count = Count; //<------- How can I get the Count from the List returned by the Load method?
            return (x % 2) == 0;
        });

        System.Console.WriteLine("Count = {0} and there are {1} even numbers", count, even.Count);
    }

    static List<int> Load()
    {
        List<int> array = new List<int>();
        int[] vet = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        array.AddRange(vet);

        return array;
    }
```

Here's the original code - just to illustrate why I didn't want to create a new List, because it will only be a temporary list without any other use.

```
private List<MailItem> Find<T_Item, T_Adaptor>(T_Adaptor adaptor, MailItemId MailId)
{
    List<T_Item> Items = ((List<T_Item>)(typeof(T_Adaptor).InvokeMember(
            "Load",
            BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
            null, adaptor,
            new Object[] { null, MailId, null }))).FindAll(
                delegate(T_Item itm)
                {
                    MailItem mi = itm as MailItem;
                    if (mi == null) return false;
                    return (mi.StateInd.Code == StateInd.ASSIGNED); 
                });

    List<MailItem> mailItems = new List<MailItem>();
    foreach (T_Item itm in Items)
        mailItems.Add(itm as MailItem);

    return mailItems;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the list reference isn't available to your code since it only lives on the stack as part of temporary expression results used during the call chain.

As such, your only option is to explicitly store it away into a variable before using it.

In this example, I would do this:

```
var list = Load();
List<int> even = list.FindAll(delegate(int x)
{
    count = list.Count;
    return (x % 2) == 0;
});
```

Of course, now you can simply do:

```
var list = Load();
int count = list.Count;
List<int> even = list.FindAll(delegate(int x)
{
    return (x % 2) == 0;
});
```

And also rewrite to a lambda:

```
var list = Load();
int count = list.Count;
List<int> even = list.FindAll(x => (x % 2) == 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var load = Load();
List<int> even = load.FindAll(delegate(int x)
{
    count = load.Count;
    return (x % 2) == 0;
});
```

Edit:
One more idea about how to achieve the result you want using extension methods as syntactical sugar:

```
static public class ListExt
{
    static public List<T> StoreSize<T>(this List<T> self, out int size)
    {
        size = (self != null) ? self.Count : -1;
        return self;
    }
}
...
List<int> even = Load().StoreSize(out count).FindAll(x => (x % 2) == 0);
```

Comment: I know I can do this, but the question is, can I access that member without assigning to a local variable?

Comment: No, you can't access it without a reference to it, and the reference is not passed to the delegate, so it's lost as part of the temporary expression results.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, Ok so I will consider this as the right answer. Could you just please edit your answer with this comment, as all the rest of code I already knew that can be done.

Comment: Your delegate function gets only one list item as input, so the information about `Count` should come from the "outer" variables caught by the closure. So it seems that you have to give a name to the temporary list.

Comment: @Andres: Vlad is right. A delegate is a closure, meaning that it will capture any variables declared on the outer scope. So you need to assing the `Load()` method result to a temp variable. The delegate cannot directly access any state from the associated list object.

Comment: @Andres: added one more method :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> nums = Load();
List<int> even = nums.FindAll(delegate(int x)
        {
            count = nums.Count;
            return (x % 2) == 0;
        });
```

Otherwise, the object you need is not in the scope of the delagate.